# Conditionally Map Components for Routes on Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I would like to create a route that displays a component conditionally.

For example, a user hits the /home route. If the user is a mentor, display MentorHomeComponent; otherwise display MenteeHomeComponent.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one short way :

**Home.vue**

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      mentor: false
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.mentor ? this.$router.push({name : 'MentorHomeComponent'}) 
                : this.$router.push({name : 'MenteeHomeComponent'})
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<component :is="componentName"></component>`. Just display appropriate component depending on user privileges, using `computed` property.

```
<template lang="pug">
  component(:is="appropriateComponent")
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  components: {
    FirstComponent: () => import("@/views/FirstComponent"),
    SecondComponent: () => import("@/views/SecondComponent")
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters("user", ["isAdmin"]),
    appropriateComponent() {
      return this.isAdmin ? "FirstComponent" : "SecondComponent";
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Good answer but you used Pug html and Vuex store which are not included by the OP , also he is using Vue-router and you didn't include that either  : Q : "Conditionally Map Components for Routes on Vue Router"